# How to inform the owner of a site about a vulnerability if there is no feedback form?

Tags: penetration-test, web-service, disclosure

Recently, I noticed several resources that may be in danger, but I did not find a feedback form or email or another way to contact the owner and warn. How can I notify the owners?

DoS seems to me a noticeable, but in a very rude way to pay attention to the problem. Maybe there is something better? What is the right thing to do in this case?

"resources" is mainly IP addresses where the IoT site is. There are no owners contacts on the sites. It is possible that the owners are private persons. I don't know how to report a threat in such a case. I think there are a lot of such.

Comment: You provide quite a lot of extra details on Reddit which would have been very helpful here. In short, you can't. And I agree with the comment "If you're going to try to notify every home webcam owner who has an insecure configuration, you're going to have a never-ending task."

Comment: @schroeder I thought it could somehow automate. I tried to automatically look for email on sites whose addresses are on the lists, and automatically strain the letter with a warning to this address. The script very rarely finds something. Over the past couple of months, only 4 times. It is not known whether these letters have come. Perhaps they are in the spam folder.